# How can I forward sent messages from one discord server to a separate channel in a different server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, replit

Title. I couldn't find anything on this online or on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a message event listener which collects all messages, and then use `client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID").send(message.content)`.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if(message.guild.id !== "GUILD ID MESSAGES ARE RECEIVED IN") return;
  client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL ID").send(message.content)
})
```